New laptop speaker has developed regular clicking during audio playback
I have a new laptop purchased just less than a month ago - a Lenovo Legion 5 16IRX9. Today it has developed a weird behaviour where the left speaker makes a regular clicking noise while it's playing audio, and for a few seconds afterward. This behaviour exists outside of Windows, during boot up. When it happens during boot it doesn't seem to be preceeded by a tone being played. I primarily use bluetooth earbuds which are functioning normally.
This feels like a hardware issue, as occurring outside of Windows would suggest that it's not a driver issue.
A recording of the sound is available here, although I expect people know what I mean by a clicking speaker. I initially suspected that the regular beat was spaced at exactly one second intervals which would've been diagnostically interesting, but analysing it seems to suggest that it's more like 1.05 seconds.
I opened the laptop up about a week ago to upgrade the memory. I don't think I damaged anything, and the issue only started today.
Is there any way this could be a software issue, or should I assume that I have a hardware fault? Any ideas about the cause? I don't actually think I'm likely to use the speakers, but I'm obviously concerned that this could be indicative of deeper problems. I'm reasonably knowledgable from the programmer perspective, but this is outside of my wheelhouse. I suspect that I need to return this laptop, but I'd really rather not deal with all that obviously.

A loudspeaker is just an output transducer; it cannot make a noise by itself. Any noise must be coming from somewhere else.

A common cause of noise is a nearby cell phone or other source of electromagnetic radiation. Be sure that cell phones and other sources of interference are kept away from the PC and external speakers.

To rule out software, boot the machine from USB, e.g., Ubuntu Live or Hiren's BootCD USB. That would eliminate any issue with the operating system or software (or HDD, too).
If there is no clicking noise when running from USB, then go back to the normal Windows OS, and use Task Manager to check what processes are running, and see if killing one stops the clicks.



I'm fairly confident that there's no external source of interference. This behaviour remains the same wherever I move the laptop in the house. As I said in the question, it occurs both inside Windows and outside of Windows during booting as soon as the Lenovo logo is displayed, which I believe covers the USB test - unless there's a common driver being used between those two scenarios?
My assumption/fear is that an electrical issue within the laptop itself is creating some type of pulsed signal/interference which is leaking into the speaker input somehow.

It could be the WiFi antenna in the case was moved near an audio trace or component, or a fan cycling, causing a current spike near an audio path. Since you opened the laptop, look also for any EMI shielding not making good contact.
